# Is changing the IIS virtual directory path a good no-downtime upgrade strategy for ASP.NET (4.6) web apps?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Single web server setup. We're thinking about setting up the app in two directories, side by side, and switching between them when doing the upgrade:

1. Let's say those two directories are "webA" and "webB"
2. The web app is set up to use one of them, let's say "webA"

Now, when we want to upgrade:

3. we set up the new version in "webB"
4. we test using a separate application on IIS
5. when ready to upgrade, we change the path of the production web app

We assume the running requests would finish in the old location and all new requests would start at the new location, using a new app pool process.

Is this a good idea or could this cause problems to users using the application during the upgrade?

Comment: It would be better to set up two separate sites, and then use ARR to switch between them. Switching traffic on ARR is more efficient (and also less troublesome) than actually switch physical paths of IIS entities (like virtual directories).

Comment: @LexLi so you would "load balance" between "webA" and "webB" using ARR on a single server, correct? I assume one of the advantages would be that you can start with moving only a part of the users and once you can see "webB" is working fine you move the rest...

Comment: No. You don't need "load balancing" when you don't. ARR can give you a pure reverse proxy to route traffic, and load balancing is something optional.

Comment: I think this is a workaround for version change but it is not a good strategy for real-life application. Since change directory for an on-line production server would be a bad operation.  I agree to set up different site and reverse proxy. So that when you need to change your version to webB, you only need to change the {HTTP_HOST} in your rewrite rule.